# Identityserver4 doesn't work by ip address

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I've used IdentityServer4 with asp net core Web, all works fine when debug in localhost:50481, but when I use myipaddress:50481 on the same computer and debug mode, it failed. I do not use a temporary credential, instead, I created a RSA cert:

```
 .AddSigningCredential(Config.GetSigningCertificate()) 

  public static RsaSecurityKey GetSigningCertificate()
  {
     var filename = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "certificateKey.rsa");

        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            var keyFile = File.ReadAllText(filename);
            var tempKey = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TemporaryRsaKey>(keyFile, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new RsaKeyContractResolver() });

            return CreateRsaSecurityKey(tempKey.Parameters, tempKey.KeyId);
        }
        else
        {
            var key = CreateRsaSecurityKey();

            RSAParameters parameters;

            if (key.Rsa != null)
                parameters = key.Rsa.ExportParameters(includePrivateParameters: true);
            else
                parameters = key.Parameters;

            var tempKey = new TemporaryRsaKey
            {
                Parameters = parameters,
                KeyId = key.KeyId
            };

            File.WriteAllText(filename, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempKey, new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = new RsaKeyContractResolver() }));

            return CreateRsaSecurityKey(tempKey.Parameters, tempKey.KeyId);
        }
  }
```

I also checked the jwks of localhost and ipaddress, they are matched.

When I publish the project to local IIS, localhost does not work too, present a 500 Internal error.

all the url in my app is "http://localhost:50481"

Answer (score 1):

I have to say this is a stupid mistake, I have not notice the authConfig,

```
let config;

if (window.location.hostname === 'localhost') {
   config = configForDevelopment;
} else {
    config = configForProduction;
}
```

when I use ip address, the config is switch to prod, change localhost to my ip address make sense.

hope it could others.